# Not happy in my job as software engineer, should I contact another company that previously made me an offer?

Tags: job-offer, resignation, probation

After my graduation I interviewed with multiple companies for a job as a software engineer. I got two offers that really interested me, accepted one and declined the other.

5 months in my job, the company seems satisfied with me, but I have the feeling that I have learnt very little and I have discovered that engineers are asked to develop quickly instead of with quality, which frustrates me. It's well paid but I don't find myself stimulated.

At the time I took this job I had another offer that I declined. It's a company in another domain, and it's a good one. I kept in touch with them and I haven't burnt bridges. I am starting to regret choosing the first offer over the second one.

Since my probation period in my company ends in one months, I am starting to feel like if I commit to it for a much longer period, I will be expressing remorse every day. What would the other company think of me if I contacted then to ask if they would be interested in me?

Comment: It is quite common for the first job out of school to be a bad fit. Make sure you've given yourself enough time for introspection to understand what it _really_ was that did not work out between you and your employer, and then, consider why you think this other job will be different. Unfortunately it is also quite common for people to leave jobs and end up in exactly the same type of situation they're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

You should, but **keep it positive**. Explain you had a hard time choosing between them and the other company. Explain why in the end you chose the other company.

Then give 1 or 2 reasons why now your views have changed, but don't become too negative.

- You're not learning very fast, but are doing routine work, and there is no promise of that changing soon.
- The focus is too much on quantity instead of quality.

Do be careful: often people fresh out of school carry a lot of assumptions on how the real world works, and will find they are wrong. A lot of companies focus on quantity/speed over quality, delivering 10 projects on 90% quality just brings in more money than delivering 9 projects with 95% quality.

Don't make yourself "unhirable" by requiring the world works the way you want, instead of you working the way the world wants. Be positive, show that you're willing to change if it needs to be.

Comment: +1 Company I am working for as a project manager was initially doing test driven development, but because of time constraints we had to ditch that and write code without tests. Is it good practice - no, but as Konerak has said 10 projects with 90% quality generates more money than 9 projects with 95% quality.

Answer (score 3):

If your probation ends in one month then you need to apply with the other company now.  From apply to written offer is often more than one month.  Don't worry so much about the why you are leaving.  If the prior company still wants you then they want you.  If they ask you why you are leaving just say upon reflection I think you guys are probably a better fit for me.  If they keep pushing then say I would rather work in your domain.  Stay away from negative - even quantity over quality might not come off as positive.

Answer (score 0):

Contacting the other company certainly won't hurt... but after 5 months, the position you interviewed is long gone. If f they have an opening that requires similar skills, you will almost certainly have to go through the whole interviewing process again, and will be competing against a different group of people.

If you are going to look elsewhere, plan on doing the whole job search again, rather than just asking that one company.

Make sure you know exactly what you want to be different, and make sure your expectations are reasonable, before you start. And be prepared to explain that when you are being interviewed, or companies may worry that you won't last with them either. As others have said, though, 5 months is a short enough time to suggest your expectations may be unreasonable, unless something is exceptionally wrong with your current employer.